# Open ViewController on button click

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am new to iOS, can any one please help me to open and activity on Button click.

I have tried below methods, but the app remains on same ViewController, i am using Singleview Application type

```
 Second *sec = [[Second alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];

 Second *sec = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondV"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
```

can anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to go through documentation provided by Apple for getting some idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using storyboard then Embed your viewcontroller to UINavigationController Editor->EmbedIn->NavigationController try this

Comment: ok, faster way than mine @Sam ;-). Not using storyboard so much, learned something from you, too ;-).

Answer (score 3):

If not using Storyboard, then following might help:

```
Second *sec = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
```

For Storyboard enabled code:

```
Second *sec = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifierForVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
```

BTW, I strongly suggest you to google the problem for solution & search SatckOverflow - first, before posting as a new question.

Also, you should reconsider the naming for the class. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your Valuable comments

Answer (score 0):

to push to another view controller you need to set a `UINavigationController` in front of your `UIViewController` in storyboard. Your `self.navigationController` might be nil, that's why it is not pushing your view controller.

Therefore drag and drop a **Navigation Controller** to your storyboard and delete the default TableViewController (make sure to click on empty space in storyboard before selecting and deleting it) and connect the UINavigationController to your own 'single view controller' by right-clicking on the yellow arrow and connecting the rootViewController outlet with it).

Then, select the UINavigationController on your storyboard and in **Attributes Inspector** (the fourth symbol in the right panel) under the section **View Controller** select **Is Initial View Controller**.

Comment: Whenever i use drag and drop Navigation Controller, it drops TableviewControler also. I do not have to work with TableView, I want to fire this code on Button Click

Comment: Yes. Then delete this tableViewController (select and press delete) and set your view controller as root view controller of the navigation controller (as described above, with right-clicking and connecting. Updated my answer accordingly).